# How can I refactor these common controller methods?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, refactoring

I have a few controller methods that are extremely similar and I was wondering what the best way to refactor them would be. First thing that comes to mind would be somehow passing in two blocks to a helper method, but I'm not sure how to do that either.

```
def action_a
  if @last_updated.nil?
    @variable_a = @stuff_a
  else
    @variable_a = (@stuff_a.select{ |item| item.updated_at > @last_updated }
  end
end

def action_b
  if @last_updated.nil?
    @variable_b = @stuff_b.some_method
  else
    @variable_b = @stuff_b.some_method.select{ |stuff| item.updated_at > @last_updated }
  end
end
```

It just seems like I'm constantly checking if `@last_updated` is nil (I set the `@last_updated` instance variable in a `before_filter`. If I could somehow pass the stuff inside the `if` as a block and the stuff in the `else` as another block, then I could remove the `if @last_updated.nil?` duplication?

What is the best way of accomplishing this for many methods?

**Update**

Where I specify `@stuff_a` and `@stuff_b`, they are always returning an array (since I use `.select`).

Comment: do you need to have separate names for `@variable_a/b` and `@stuff_a/b` ?

Comment: Yes. An example is `@users` and `@courses`. I'm essentially returning the array, or returning only those that have been updated since the `@last_updated` time. Great question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to extract your condition in a separate `def` block and use it later on:

```
def select_updates a
  @last_updated.nil? ? a : a.select{ |item| item.updated_at > @last_updated }
end
def action_a; @variable_a = select_updates(@stuff_a) end
def action_b; @variable_b = select_updates(@stuff_b.some_method) end
```

Comment: They were all good answers. This is ultimately the one I ended up going with.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at this. It's DRYer and should yield identical results.

```
def action_a
  do_the_processing :"@variable_a", @stuff_a
end

def action_b
  do_the_processing :"@variable_b", @stuff_b.some_method
end

private
def do_the_processing var_name, collection
  if @last_updated.nil?
    instance_variable_set var_name, collection
  else
    instance_variable_set var_name, collection.select{ |item| item.updated_at > @last_updated }
  end
end
```

### Update

And here's the two blocks approach (just for fun) (uses 1.9's stabby lambda syntax)

```
def action_a
  check_last_updated is_nil: -> { @variable_a = @stuff_a },
                     is_not_nil: -> { @variable_a = (@stuff_a.select{ |item| item.updated_at > @last_updated } }
end

def action_b
  check_last_updated is_nil: -> { @variable_b = @stuff_b.some_method },
                     is_not_nil: -> { @variable_b = @stuff_b.some_method.select{ |stuff| item.updated_at > @last_updated } }
end

private
def check_last_updated blocks = {}
  if @last_updated.nil?
    blocks[:is_nil].try(:call)
  else
    blocks[:is_not_nil].try(:call)
  end
end
```

Comment: Also be sure to make `do_the_processing` protected or private, since depending on your routing it could become callable directly

Comment: I definitely like this, before I mark it as correct I'd like to see any other suggestions. For now this is definitely plausible. Much thanks.

Answer (score 0):

AS I can see, you could do the followings

have two scope for each

Ex:

```
class Stuff < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :updated_at, lambda {|updated_date|
    {:conditions => "updated_at > #{updated_date}"}
  }
end


class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :updated_at, lambda {|updated_date|
    {:conditions => "updated_at > #{updated_date}"}
  }
end
```

in your controller do this

```
def action_a
  @variable_a = update_method(@stuff_a)
end

def action_b
  @variable_b = update_method(@stuff_b)
end

private
def update_method(obj)
  result = nil
  if @last_updated.nil?
    result = obj.some_method 
  else    
    result = obj.some_method.updated_at(@last_updated) 
  end  
  result 
end
```

HTH